# Magento - unable to create admin order with IE8. (Possiably PHP/JS/AJAX)

Tags: php, javascript, magento

**Magento Build:** 1.5.1.0

**PHP Version:** 5

We are currently unable to create a new order within Magento Admin when using IE (Internet Explorer) 8. 
 The system allows us to see customers, however nothing happens when you click on a customer.

We get the following “error on page” details:

> Line: 691   Error: ‘AdminOrder’ is undefined
>
> Line: 1129   Error: ‘order.selectCustomer’ is null or not an object
>
> Line: 1153   Error: ‘order’ is null or not an object
>
> Line: 1769   Error: ‘order.productGridRowClick’ is null or not an
>   object
>
> Line: 1842   Error: ‘order’ is null or not an object
>
> Line: 1847   Error: ‘order’ is null or not an object
>
> Line: 2198   Error: ‘order’ is null or not an object
>
> Line: 2219   Error: ‘order’ is null or not an object
>
> Line: 2572   Error: ‘order’ is null or not an object
>
> Line: 2691   Error: ‘order’ is null or not an object
>
> Line: 2708   Error: ‘order’ is null or not an object
>
> Line: 2728   Error: ‘order’ is null or not an object
>
> Line: 2853   Error: ‘order’ is null or not an object

And the following on line 691 (if applicable)

```
var order = new AdminOrder({"store_id”:"1”,"currency_symbol”:"\u00a3”,"shipping_method_reseted”:true,"payment_method":null});
```

We have attempted full removal and re-installation of all plugins inc. cache clearing without luck. 
 A fresh install of the same magento version works fine, however we would like to avoid this if possiable.

Can provide any logs/files as necessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see different quotes in your line " and ” .. they don't seem to make love .. or is it just here on stackoverflow ?

Comment: This appears to have been changed on it’s copy and paste journey into stackoverflow. I have checked the file which is fine. Thanks for spotting it though.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some admin javascript isn't being loaded. Does the same page work when you use Firefox or Google Chrome? If so, try clearing the IE8 browser cache and/or CTRL+Refresh the page in IE8. IE will cache JS and if it's partially loaded you may encounter this kind of behavior.

If the admin doesn't work in Firefox either, you need to tell us if you installed any third party extensions, made any changes in the file structure etc...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
All other browsers (including IE9) load the content fine.
We would use an alternate browser, however unfortunately the system will need to be used by a corporate locked-down version of IE8.
All obvious refresh etc has been done, incl compatibility mode, URL forcing etc without luck.

Last night we attempted to replace core Magento back end files including /app/adminhtml, app/code and /js without luck.
If anyone is aware of any other core files that are loaded during this process that may be causing an issue, please let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to provide a comprehensive list of all the extensions that have been installed/reinstalled etc as I simply do not have this information available to me. I have however removed all installed extensions, cleared the cache and tested with the same problem. This does not eliminate the possibility however of a broken uninstall in the past. 

Thanks.